# labeling 2d contour plot from table in gnuplot

Tags: plot, gnuplot, contour

I need to create a 2D contour plot using gnuplot with data table. I'm not sure how to label the contours.

**I cannot use splot feature to create contour labels because I would like to add 2D plots on top of contour plots.**

Below is code to replicate to create a **2D** contour plot. My question is how to create labels using the data table.

```
reset
f(x,y)=(x**2+y-11)**2+(x+y**2-7)**2
set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set isosample 250, 250
set table 'test1.dat'
splot f(x,y)
unset table

set contour base
set cntrparam levels disc 450,250,150,100,60,30,10,2 
unset surface
set table 'cont1.dat'
splot f(x,y)
unset table


reset session

set terminal wxt size 800,600 enhanced font 'Verdana,10' persist


set style arrow 2 head nofilled size screen 0.03,15 ls 2 lc rgb "blue"

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
unset key
#set palette rgbformulae 33,13,10

p 'cont1.dat' w l lt -1 lw 1.5
```

Here is the `cont1.dat` looks like based on running the above code. The final column is the label that I would like to have it the contour plot.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear to me whether you are talking about "labels" of the contour or "keys" (or legend) of the contours.
Here is a minimized example for both possibilities. I assume you've just chosen a function for demo purposes but your data will be from a file.

A trick to avoid the gap in curves (without external script) is to skip 5 lines and `set datafile commentschar " "` and take `columnheader(5)`. The lines like `# Contour 0, label:        2` are then considered as data where the 5th column is your key. Apparently, the actual data is nevertheless (or luckily) not interpreted as comments although the commentschar is set to space.

**Code:**

```
### contour lines with labels
reset session

f(x,y)=(x**2+y-11)**2+(x+y**2-7)**2

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set isosample 250, 250

set contour base
set cntrparam levels disc 450,250,150,100,60,30,10,2 
unset surface
set table $Contour
    splot f(x,y)
unset table

set style textbox opaque noborder

set multiplot layout 2,1
    plot $Contour u 1:2 w l lw 1.5 notitle, '' u 1:2:3 every 50 w labels boxed notitle

    set datafile commentschar " "
    plot for [i=1:8] $Contour u 1:2:(i) skip 5 index i-1 w l lw 1.5 lc var title columnheader(5)
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

**Addition:**

If you add the line

```
set key top left opaque box
```

and exchange the plot command to:

```
plot for [i=1:8] $Contour u 1:2 skip 5 index i-1 w l lw 1.5 lc 0 dt i title columnheader(5)
```

You will get the following:

Note that there are only 5 predefined dash types which will be repeated, however, you can define your own dash patterns (see `help dashtype`).

[image]

Comment: your plots look crisp and clear, can you please let me know what font, page size, terminal, aspect ratio you used?

Comment: This was on Win7, `wxt` terminal, size happend to be 568x643 px and then saved in the interactive terminal as PNG file. The font is the standard one. Well, I don't know (yet) how to find out what the name of the font actually is.

Comment: did you actually look for the first or the second plot? If you combine the second plot with some more plots (as you wrote) then the `commentschar " "` could maybe cause some unwanted results. You need be aware and need to check.

Comment: I have played with `commentschars`, but I did not know about the `skip`. Good to know.

Comment: @theozh it works perfectly, this is a clever solution. Please take a look at alternative solution which goes into writing bash script http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~zov1/gnuplot/html/contour.html. Yours is very simple and works well.

Comment: @theozh one more question what if I have to change the lie type to say dotted for once contour, dashed for second contour and solid for third contour and so on, is it possible to do it? bascially I'm asking if we could have a different line type instead of color? Thanks

Comment: so I assume you were asking for the second plot. See addition,,,

Comment: @theozh I have a question on contour plot and hatched lines, can you please let me know if you would be able to help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57118566/gnuplot-contour-plot-hatched-lines

Answer (score 1):

I think you want something like this:

```
datafile = 'cont1.dat'
stats datafile nooutput
plot for [i=0: STATS_blocks-1] datafile index i title columnhead(3) w l
```

The `stats` command collects some statistical information about the datafile, especially it counts the number of blocks. Blocks are separated by two empty lines, and each block corresponds to a different contour level.

The `columnheads(3)` command takes the entry in the third column of the first line in each block as title.

Unfortunately, in your case, because of the `columnhead` command, the first line is interpreted as header line and skipped for plotting. This leads to gaps in the resulting diagram:

[image: with gaps]

I would suggest some preprocessing to generate a headerline without using the first dataline. The simplest thing which worked for me was to remove the `#` at the beginning of the comment lines which start each block. I'm on Linux, so I use `sed`:

```
sed "s/# Contour/Contour/" -i cont1.dat
```

This can be called from gnuplot, and the final script looks like this:

```
reset

# We need the datafile several times
datafile = 'cont1.dat'

f(x,y)=(x**2+y-11)**2+(x+y**2-7)**2

set xrange [0:5]
set yrange [0:5]
set isosample 250, 250

# Generate data
set contour base
set cntrparam levels disc 450,250,150,100,60,30,10,2 
set view map
unset surface
set table datafile
splot f(x,y)
unset table

# Count blocks
stats datafile nooutput

system("sed \"s/# Contour/Contour/\" -i ".datafile)

# Plot each data block separatly and set the title to 
# the first entry of the third column of the respective block
plot for [i=0: STATS_blocks-1] datafile index i title columnhead(4) w l
```

[image: without gaps]

One drawback: The datafile after the `sed` command contains some invalid lines "Contour 0, label:", without the comment hash # and without a label number. They are ignored by gnuplot because they don't contain valid data.