# gnuplot epslatex unable to get replot

Tags: latex, gnuplot

When I use `replot` in the epslatex terminal, anything I `replot` is not showing up in the final output.

```
reset session
set terminal epslatex size 5.0in,4in color colortext font ',10' standalone

set output 'plots.tex'

set size square

plot sin(x)
replot cos(x)

set output
```

[image]

When I use `,` and plot in the same line, I get correct outputs.

```
reset session
set terminal epslatex size 5.0in,4in color colortext font ',10' standalone

set output 'plots.tex'

set size square

plot sin(x), cos(x)

set output
```

[image]

`replot` is very convenient becuase I can use `set` and change settings.

My question is how to use `replot` in `gnuplot` that prints in LaTeX.

Comment: although a rather old question, but maybe still of interest. Which settings do you want to change between `plot` and `replot`? The final plot will have the later settings. So, why exactly can't you use the syntax with plot commands separated by `,`? Please make an example. Are you maybe typing it all in the command line instead of loading a script text file?

Answer (score -1):

In gnuplot both commands are different. Using `plot sin(x)` followed by `replot cos(x)` draws *two* plots: one with sin(x) and another one with the result of the previous plot command (ie sin(x)) and cos(x). Indeed

```
plot sin(x)
replot cos(x)
```

is absolutely equivalent to

```
plot sin(x)
plot sin(x), cos(x)
```

If you display the 'plots-inc.eps' or if you change the terminal to pdf, you have two pages, the first with the plot of sin(x) and the second with both.

The plots.tex file is supposed to be included in a some tex source and only contains one plot. The actual function that is plotted in the .tex file is the last one (with sin(x) and cos(x)). This code is adapted to dvi output  and if you format it with `latex plots.tex` (and not `pdflatex plots.tex`) and view the .dvi file with xdvi (or whatever), you can verify that a plot with both functions is present. For unknown reasons, with pdflatex, only the sin(x) appears (but both are in the .tex code and there is the legend for cos(x)).

Here is what I get in the .dvi file:
[image]

We can do a zoom on this dvi file.

[image]

And compare it to the second plot if we use a pdf terminal.

[image]

As you can see, the plot rendering is worse with the dvi file and the function is smoother with the pdf output.

I think the problem is that the epslatex terminal is a very old driver. It was the default in the nineties, but with modern TeX engines, almost no one uses it anymore and I am not sure that it is actively maintained.

This probably explains the problems : the incomplete plot with pdflatex and the lower quality of the rendering. Most probably this driver has never really been adapted to engines like pdflatex or lualatex.

Unless you absolutely need dvi, I would suggest you to switch to another driver.  Generate your plots as pdf and use `\includegraphics` to load them.  The plot quality will be increased, but you will also gain  all the flexibility of `\includegraphics` to resize, rotate, clip or do whatever you want to your plots.

Please note that the pdf driver will generate one plot per page and with your initial code there are two plots. You can include a specific page (ie plot) of the pdf with the 'page=' option of `\includegraphics`, but the simpler is to select different output files per plot.

```
set output 'plots.pdf'
plot sin(x)
set output 'plots2.pdf'
replot cos(x)
```

Comment: You cannot compare the screen rendering of a Postscript image via a dvi-viewer with a pdf displayed with a pdf-reader. To be fair you must compare the pdf-output of both results! Yes, the actual problem is, that `replot` works fine for screen terminals (wxt, qt, x11, windows), but not for file terminals. And file termianls behave differently: for eps/pdf it creates multiple pages, pngcairo ignores the replot, svg creates a corrupt file, etc.